# Cotangent vectors as equivalence classes of co-curves?

Tags: manifolds, tangent-spaces, co-tangent-space

In manifold theory, tangent vectors can be seen as equivalence classes of curves. Using the definition in Weintraub's *Differential Forms: Theory and Practice*, let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold and $p \in U \subset M$. Let $k: O \rightarrow U$ be a coordinate chart where $O \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be the parametrizations of two curves on $M$ with $r_1(0) = r_2(0) = p$. We say that these two curves are equivalent if $(k^{−1} \circ r_1)'(0) = (k^{−1} \circ r_2)'(0) $. Then the tangent vectors to $M$ at $p$ are defined as the equivalence classes of curves on $M$ passing through $p$.

I wonder if cotangent vectors to $M$ can be seen as equivalence classes of any "co-curves" on $M$.

Comment: They're usually defined as equivalence classes of *functions* $M\to\mathbb{R}$, not curves.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you elaborate? For example, what is the equivalence relation involved?

Comment: There are several equivalent ways to construct it; the one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotangent_space#Alternative_definition) is pretty standard. The basic idea is that there are multiple intrinsic notions of two functions $f,g\in C^\infty M$ having "the same first derivative" at $p$, and in that case we have $f\sim_p g$, and we define $T^*_pM:=C^\infty M/\sim_p$ with the induced vector space structure.